# CSV Rows to XML files using Python

Tags: python, xml, csv

I have csv file that looks like this:

```
artist,year,id,video_name,new_video_id,file_root_name,video_type
,,,,,,
Clay Aiken,1,clay_aiken,Sorry Seems To Be...,sorry-seems-to-be,02_sc_ca_sorry,FLV
Clay Aiken,1,clay_aiken,Everything I Do (I Do It For You),everything-i-do-i-do-it-for-you,03_sc_ca_everything,FLV
Clay Aiken,1,clay_aiken,A Thousand Days,a-thousand-days,04_sc_ca_thousandda,FLV
Clay Aiken,1,clay_aiken,Here You Come Again,here-you-come-again,05_sc_ca_hereyoucom,FLV
Clay Aiken,1,clay_aiken,Interview,interview,06_sc_ca_intv,FLV
```

Each row from above would generate a separate xml file like below (5 to be precise):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE smil PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SMIL 2.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/SMIL20.dtd">
<smil xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/Language">
  <head>
    <meta base="rtmp://cp23636.edgefcs.net/ondemand" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <switch>
      <video src="mp4:soundcheck/%year/%id/%file_root_name_256.mp4" system-bitrate="336000"/>
      <video src="mp4:soundcheck/%year/%id/%file_root_name_512.mp4" system-bitrate="592000"/>
      <video src="mp4:soundcheck/%year/%id/%file_root_name_768.mp4" system-bitrate="848000"/>
      <video src="mp4:soundcheck/%year/%id/%file_root_name_1128.mp4" system-bitrate="1208000"/>
    </switch>
  </body>
</smil>
```

Naming it %new_video_id.smil

I've figured out how to parse the csv file:

```
import csv
import sys

f = open(sys.argv[1], 'rU')
reader = csv.reader(f)
for row in reader:
    year = row[1]
    id = row[2]
    file_root_name = row[5]
    print year, id, file_root_name
```

How to I take each of the variables and include when writing the xml file?

Comment: why don't you build the xml while iterating through the csv?

Comment: not a single xml, each row is a new xml.

Comment: do you need to build this in memory or save each xml file to the disk?

Comment: @DavidNeudorfer What you mean is that each row is `video` tag in a single xml file?

Comment: each row will be a new xml file written to disk. each file will be be named using the `new_video_id` variable

Comment: Python 2.x: ALWAYS open a csv file in BINARY mode ('rb' when reading, 'wb' when writing)

Comment: for clarification your example csv would generate 5 **XML** files

Comment: @JohnMachin yes thank you for catching that.

Comment: @JohnMachin I used `rU` because when I use `rb` I get: 

`_csv.Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?`

Comment: Did you have to look up Clay Aiken's body of work to make this example? `:D`

Comment: @Droogans  *woosh* Over my head. Is this an American Idol or Monty Python joke?

Comment: DavidNeudorfer neither. I read the question, thought about it, and when I came back to it, I read it again and went, *hold on a second, is this Clay Aiken's discography?* Focusing on the question became harder, admittedly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd start with something like this:

```
import csv
import sys

from xml.etree import ElementTree
from xml.dom import minidom

video_data = ((256, 336000),
              (512, 592000),
              (768, 848000),
              (1128, 1208000))

with open(sys.argv[1], 'rU') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        switch_tag = ElementTree.Element('switch')

        for suffix, bitrate in video_data:
            attrs = {'src': ("mp4:soundcheck/{year}/{id}/{file_root_name}_{suffix}.mp4"
                             .format(suffix=str(suffix), **row)),
                     'system-bitrate': str(bitrate),
                     }
            ElementTree.SubElement(switch_tag, 'video', attrs)
        print minidom.parseString(ElementTree.tostring(switch_tag)).toprettyxml()
```

Basically as the csv file is parsed, an xml document is created using the attributes in the row to create video tags one by one.

Example output (for one row):

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<switch>
    <video src="mp4:soundcheck/1/clay_aiken/02_sc_ca_sorry_256.mp4" system-bitrate="336000"/>
    <video src="mp4:soundcheck/1/clay_aiken/02_sc_ca_sorry_512.mp4" system-bitrate="592000"/>
    <video src="mp4:soundcheck/1/clay_aiken/02_sc_ca_sorry_768.mp4" system-bitrate="848000"/>
    <video src="mp4:soundcheck/1/clay_aiken/02_sc_ca_sorry_1128.mp4" system-bitrate="1208000"/>
</switch>
```

Note: ElementTree doesn't support pretty printing, so I used the trick explained in [PyMOTW](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/xml/etree/ElementTree/create.html#pretty-printing-xml).

Comment: I'm trying to create an xml file for each row and not an a single xml file with all rows. How would I modify this to do that?

Comment: @DavidNeudorfer I've updated my answer to do that. You just need to move the part that creates the xml file into the for loop to generate a new xml for each row.

Comment: @DavidNeudorfer I see, I've changed the code to generate multiple video tags for each csv row.

Comment: this is exactly what I needed but I'm still having trouble grasping xml manipulation in python and have followed up your script with a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674610/including-additional-static-xml-with-python

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider treating your XML template as a format string:  create a string whose value is the XML, replace all of that `%year`, `%id`, and `%file_root_name`. with `%s`, and then you can do:

```
 print xml_template % [year, id, file_root_name] * 3
```

This will only work, mind you, if the data in your csv contains XML-legal characters that don't need to be escaped; you need to preprocess each value to convert markup characters (`<`, `>`, `'`, `"`) to entities (`&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&apos;`, `&quot;`).

It's safer to use minidom and ElementTree to build your XML, as jcollado suggests.