# including additional static xml with python

Tags: python, xml

I need my current script to include additional xml. This is the script in its current form:

```
import csv
import sys

from xml.etree import ElementTree
from xml.dom import minidom

video_data = ((256, 336000),
              (512, 592000),
              (768, 848000),
              (1128, 1208000))

with open(sys.argv[1], 'rU') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        switch_tag = ElementTree.Element('switch')

        for suffix, bitrate in video_data:
            attrs = {'src': ("mp4:soundcheck/{year}/{id}/{file_root_name}_{suffix}.mp4"
                             .format(suffix=str(suffix), **row)),
                     'system-bitrate': str(bitrate),
                     }
            ElementTree.SubElement(switch_tag, 'video', attrs)
        print minidom.parseString(ElementTree.tostring(switch_tag)).toprettyxml()
```

It currently outputs this xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
   <switch>
      <video src="mp4:soundcheck/2006/clay_aiken/02_sc_ca_sorry_256.mp4" system-bitrate="336000"/>
      <video src="mp4:soundcheck/2006/clay_aiken/02_sc_ca_sorry_512.mp4" system-bitrate="592000"/>
      <video src="mp4:soundcheck/2006/clay_aiken/02_sc_ca_sorry_768.mp4" system-bitrate="848000"/>
      <video src="mp4:soundcheck/2006/clay_aiken/02_sc_ca_sorry_1128.mp4" system-bitrate="1208000"/>
    </switch>
```

I need to include additional information in the header and footer of the xml file. See example below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE smil PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SMIL 2.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/SMIL20.dtd">
<smil xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/Language">
  <head>
    <meta base="rtmp://cp23636.edgefcs.net/ondemand" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <switch>
      <video src="mp4:soundcheck/2006/clay_aiken/02_sc_ca_sorry_256.mp4" system-bitrate="336000"/>
      <video src="mp4:soundcheck/2006/clay_aiken/02_sc_ca_sorry_512.mp4" system-bitrate="592000"/>
      <video src="mp4:soundcheck/2006/clay_aiken/02_sc_ca_sorry_768.mp4" system-bitrate="848000"/>
      <video src="mp4:soundcheck/2006/clay_aiken/02_sc_ca_sorry_1128.mp4" system-bitrate="1208000"/>
    </switch>
  </body>
</smil>
```

How can I update my current script to include this static information as well as the variable's that are being pulled from the csv in the scripts current form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you replace

```
 print minidom.parseString(ElementTree.tostring(switch_tag)).toprettyxml()
```

with

```
 print header + ElementTree.tostring(switch_tag) + footer
```

Where `header` and `footer` are what is above and below the switch tag in your second example output, respectively. Alternatively, if you want to use the `prettyxml()`, remove the first line from its output.

```
 '\n'.join(minidom.parseString(ElementTree.tostring(switch_tag)).toprettyxml().splitlines()[1:])
```

Comment: That is exactly what I want todo but I can't figure out how to make header and footer equal multiple lines with the correct spacing.

Comment: Still having problems but this really did help. Thanks @ninjarabbit.

Comment: Ah, you need to join the lines after splitting them. Edited.
Hope you figured it out.